# Silverlight DependencyProperty.SetCurrentValue Equivalent

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, silverlight-4.0, dependency-properties, setcurrentvalue

I'm looking for a SL4 equivalent to .NET 4's [SetCurrentValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.setcurrentvalue.aspx) API, which would appear to be exactly what I need for my scenario.

In short, I'm writing an attached behavior that updates the value of a given property at appropriate times. However, I don't want it to overwrite any bindings that are set on that dependency property. I merely want to push that value to the property (and therefore have any bindings refresh based on that value).

From what I can tell, there's no easy way to do this yet in SL4.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silverlight does not provide direct access to this level of dependency value.  However its this level of value that Animations in storyboards set when they manipulate a property.

Hence a Storyboard with a 0 length duration containing a single `DiscreteObjectKeyFrame` might achieve your desired result.

Comment: Just tried this and am surprised to report it seems to work. I'm surprised because it's an animation so I assumed the low precedence would cause issues. I will certainly stick with this solution if I can because it's less code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to simulate what I'm after by detecting bindings and injecting a surrogate object between the source and target. I can then manipulate the surrogate and have both sides of the original binding refresh.

It's ugly and more work than I'd like, but it seems to work.

Kent

Comment: @KentBoogaart can you help with this? I need SetCurrentValue in Silverlight/WPF cross platform code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181788/wpf-dependency-property-precedence-reference-type-default-values#comment17945942_13181788