# Silverlight detect when Dependency property has a Xaml binding

Tags: c#, silverlight, dependency-properties

Is it possible to detect when a Xaml binding is set on a DependencyProperty in Silverlight?

E.g. if I had a custom user-control with single dependency property and a binding declared like this:

```
public class MyControl : UserControl
{ 
   public static readonly DependencyProperty TestProperty = 
           DependencyProperty.Register("Test", 
              typeof(object), typeof(MyControl), 
              new PropertyMetadata(null));

   public object Test
   { 
       get { return GetValue(TestProperty); } 
       set { SetValue(TestProperty, value); } 
   }
}

<MyControl Test="{Binding APropInViewModel}>
</MyControl>
```

Can I in the MyControl code to something like this?

```
// Ctor
public MyControl()
{ 
    TestProperty.BindingChanged += new EventHandler(...)
}
```

e.g. can I get a notification of binding?

**NOTE:**

This is to solve a [tricky order of precedence problem, described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181788/wpf-dependency-property-precedence-reference-type-default-values/13182553#13182553) so just checking for new values in the DependencyPropertyChanged handler won't work - because the property changed handler doesn't fire!!

Comment: why do you want your observablecollection to be a DP at all? are you really going to replace it during runtime?

Comment: Yeah, I've created a custom control and many users are using it via code-behind (e.g. accessing default value of the properties, which in my case are collections). Some users are binding to it. 

I'm just trying to think of a good repeatable pattern for providing custom controls where some reference-type dependency properties need default values for code-behind access, and accept bindings for MVVM. It's not as easy as it sounds!

Comment: For the case when you are not going to replace the whole collection, just a plain property should be enough: binding will work with it, too. And the changes in the collection will be picked up, because it implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`. So again: the chances are high that you don't actually need a DP.

Comment: So maybe you need a different pattern for collections.

Comment: I was thinking about the problem in general: perhaps the reference-type properties don't usually need to be DPs? The reason is that for them we are usually not interested in replacing them as a whole, but rather changing their properties (which are value-typed), or properties of their reference-typed properties (again, which are value typed) and so on down the tree. So the following strategy seems to be reasonable: (1) value-type properties have to be DPs; (2) reference-type properties have to be plain properties, but derived from DependencyObject; (3) the same applies recursively.

Comment: The only small exception from this rule seems to be a collection: it has to implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` and not `INotifyPropertyChanged`, because we access its subitems by index and not by name.

Comment: Are you sure properties can be bound to if not DPs? This is in a custom usercontrol

Comment: Well, if you've got a plain property (not a field!) in the DataContext, which contains a DependencyObject, you must be able to bind to the DPs of that DependencyObject. (Through syntax like `{Binding obj.property}`.) This must work in `UserControl`s as well.

Comment: Hmm, this is worth a try. I'll give it a shot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for value changes in this binding. You can detect changes using propertychanged callback method which is static for Dependency properties.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TestProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("Test",
          typeof(object), typeof(MyControl),
          new PropertyMetadata(null, TestChangedCallbackHandler));

    private static void TestChangedCallbackHandler(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        MyControl obj = sender as MyControl;

        Test = args.NewValue; 
    }
```

However, this might cause following event listening cases. If you want to listen changes on this dependency property is explained in this link : 
[Listen DepencenyProperty value changes](http://www.amazedsaint.com/2009/12/silverlight-listening-to-dependency.html)

```
public void RegisterForNotification(string propertyName, FrameworkElement element, PropertyChangedCallback callback)
    {
        Binding b = new Binding(propertyName) { Source = element };
        var prop = System.Windows.DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "ListenAttached" + propertyName,
            typeof(object),
            typeof(UserControl),
            new System.Windows.PropertyMetadata(callback));

        element.SetBinding(prop, b);
    }
```

and call like this

```
this.RegisterForNotification("Test", this, TestChangedCallback);
```